# questdlg doesn't display buttons on Matlab 2012

Tags: matlab

I'm having some troubles in using `questdlg` on MATLAB 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2. If I try to run the first example code for `questdlg` suggested on the MATLAB webpage, the window correctly shows up, but the buttons are not there as it can be seen in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRG5V.png) attached. Also while debugging the problem is still there. Any suggestion to fix it?

**Edit:** I copy/paste the code that gives the problem from the matlab website.

```
answer = questdlg('Would you like a dessert?', ...
    'Dessert Menu', ...
    'Ice cream','Cake','No thank you','No thank you');
% Handle response
switch answer
    case 'Ice cream'
        disp([answer ' coming right up.'])
        dessert = 1;
    case 'Cake'
        disp([answer ' coming right up.'])
        dessert = 2;
    case 'No thank you'
        disp('I''ll bring you your check.')
        dessert = 0;
end
```

Comment: Is there an opportunity for you to update your MATLAB version? Getting help for an 8 year old version might be difficult, especially after the big overhaul in R2016b. The [documentation for `questdlg`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/questdlg.html) also starts off with a warning to use newer functions if possible.

Comment: Try looking at the documentation using `doc questdlg` in your MATLAB command window instead of finding the documentation online. The MathWorks website always shows the most recent docs (i.e. 2020b currently) so might not match up against what is available to you. Using the `doc` command you will see the documentation for your installed version.

Comment: @Adriaan unfortunately I can't update my version at the moment.

Comment: @Wolfie thank you for the suggestion. Actually in `doc questdlg` is reported exactly the same example and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Then it's unlikely we can help without an [mcve]

Comment: What OS are you on? Any chance it’s newer than your version of MATLAB? Might also be an issue with the installation (try reinstalling) and especially with conflicting versions of Java. We can’t help you troubleshoot your installation, unfortunately.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I use Windows Server 2012 R2.